# C# compiling optimizations: null coalescing operator - UPDATED - Reflector's bug?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, reflector, il

Greetings! I am slightly confused about how does C# compiler perform its optimizations.
I have written the following getter to make up "lazy" initialization, and default value in case of null:

*Static class Helper:*

```
private static string host;  
public static string Host  
{        
    get  
    {  
        return host ?? (host= (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"] ?? "host.ru"));  
    }  
}
```

*Here is the result of disassembling by Reflector:*

```
public static string Host 
{  
    get  
    {  
        if (Helper.host == null)  
        {  
            string host = Helper.host;  
        }  
        return (Helper.host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"] ?? "host.ru");  
    }  
}
```

Looks like it would work in other way than assumed...

*UPDATE*

```
    private static string host;
    public static string Host
    {
        get
        {
            return host ?? (host = (GetVal() ?? "default"));
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(Host);
        host = "overwritten";
        Console.WriteLine(Host);
    }
    static string GetVal()
    {
        return "From config";
    }
```

*Works correctly (From config, overwritten), but Reflector shows the same:*

```
public static string Host
{
    get
    {
        if (Program.host == null)
        {
            string host = Program.host;
        }
        return (Program.host = GetVal() ?? "default");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using C# 4.0 I'd look at using the Lazy<T> class for Lazy instantiation.

Comment: Looks quite strange to me. Almost looks like a bug in either reflector or C#. But a C# bug in such simple code sounds rather unlikely.

Comment: Perhaps somebody who understand IL can check if it's a bug in reflector

Comment: Such code works correctly in dummy console app, providing output as assumed. Looks like a bug in Reflector...   
Console.WriteLine(Host);
host = "overwritten";
Console.WriteLine(Host);

Comment: You could post it in the reflector forums so they can confirm if it's a bug and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Reflector's C# disassembly.

Starting with this code:

```
public static string _test;
public static string _setting;

public static string Test_1
{
    get { return _test ?? (_setting ?? "default"); }
}
```

Reflector shows this C# disassembly:

```
public static string Test_1
{
    get
    {
        return (_test ?? (_setting ?? "default"));
    }
}
```

and the corresponding IL:

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static string get_Test_1() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldsfld string ConsoleApplication1.Program::_test
    L_0005: dup 
    L_0006: brtrue.s L_0017
    L_0008: pop 
    L_0009: ldsfld string ConsoleApplication1.Program::_setting
    L_000e: dup 
    L_000f: brtrue.s L_0017
    L_0011: pop 
    L_0012: ldstr "default"
    L_0017: ret 
}
```

I am not an IL expert, but this is my take on it:

- `L_0000:`[`ldsfld`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldsfld.aspx) pushes `_test` onto the evaluation stack
- `L_0005:`[`dup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.dup.aspx) copies the value (`_test`) that is topmost on the evaluation stack and pushes that onto the stack.
- `L_0006:`[`brtrue.s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brtrue_s.aspx) pops the value created by `dup` off the stack and jumps to `L_0017` if it is not `null`.
- `L_0008:`[`pop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.pop.aspx) at this point, `_test` is `null`, so pop that value off the stack.

and it continues to evaluate `_setting` in a similar fashion, finally returning `"default"` if `_setting` is also `null`.

Now, if we add an assignment into the code like this:

```
public static string Test_2
{
    get { return _test ?? (_test = (_setting ?? "default")); }
}
```

Reflector shows this C# disassembly:

```
public static string Test_2
{
    get
    {
        if (_test == null)
        {
            string text1 = _test;
        }
        return (_test = _setting ?? "default");
    }
}
```

which is not correct (if `_test` is not `null`, instead of returning `_test`, it assigns `_setting` or `"default"` to `_test` and then returns).

However, the IL dissassembly looks like the IL for `Test_1`, with a couple of extra instructions at `L_0017` and `L_0018` to do the assignment.

```
.method public hidebysig specialname static string get_Test_2() cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldsfld string ConsoleApplication1.Program::_test
    L_0005: dup 
    L_0006: brtrue.s L_001d
    L_0008: pop 
    L_0009: ldsfld string ConsoleApplication1.Program::_setting
    L_000e: dup 
    L_000f: brtrue.s L_0017
    L_0011: pop 
    L_0012: ldstr "default"
    L_0017: dup 
    L_0018: stsfld string ConsoleApplication1.Program::_test
    L_001d: ret 
}
```

Finally, if you copy Reflector's C# dissembly and run it against the original, you'll see it produces different results.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _test = "Test";
            Console.WriteLine(Test_2);
            Console.WriteLine(Reflector_Test_2);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string _test;
        public static string _setting;

        public static string Test_1
        {
            get { return _test ?? (_setting ?? "default"); }
        }

        public static string Test_2
        {
            get { return _test ?? (_test = (_setting ?? "default")); }
        }

        public static string Reflector_Test_2
        {
            get
            {
                if (_test == null)
                {
                    string text1 = _test;
                }
                return (_test = _setting ?? "default");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
Test
default
```

Comment: Thanks! I have posted this issue to RedGate forum: http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?p=44297

Answer (score 0):

I guess I don't understand - both code examples are synonymous.

Remember that Reflector cannot  reproduce your exact syntax from the IL that the compiler generates.  Sometimes the syntax will be different but the semantics and meaning of the code will always be the same.

Comment: I don't see how these are synonymous. The first one calls(apart from thread-safty issues) the right expression only once, the second one calls it each time the getter is executed.

Comment: Yes, that's what confuses me, actually. No "lazy-load" at all.

Comment: @Callum Rogers: I don't see how the second one is lazy. It calls `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"]` everytime. Whereas the first one calls it only if `host==null`. And the `if` code in the second does nothing at all. It assigns to a local variable, but never reads it.